# how to avoid getting error because of undefined in React-Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, undefined

I need help. How can I avoid getting error because of undefined? I'm trying to check but I guess my method does not work.[image]

[image]

Comment: `this.props.adres` is clearly not defined. you need to make sure that exists before you try to do something to its properties (which also don't exist)

Comment: "_How can I avoid getting error because of undefined_" Stop calling functions on objects that don't exist.

Comment: the thing is that, I'm navigating to this page from two seperate pages. In first page, I send the object 'adres'. So, when I come here from that page, there is no problem. But through the second page, I do not pass any parameter or object, so it gives that error when I come from there. That is the problem, but I do not know how to solve this problem @Pabs123

Comment: @YasharogluZeynal see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you know for a fact `adres` is not there when you navigate from one of your pages, you should be checking for its existence, not the existence of its properties:

```
this.state = {
     addressLine: this.props.adres? this.props.adres.address_line:null,
     selectedBranchId: this.props.adres? this.props.adres.branch_address_id:null,
}
```

From what you've explained, this should solve the issue, though to be completely safe I would do a full check for each like:

```
this.props.adres && this.props.adres.address_line
```

Also not sure why you're spelling it as `adres` instead of `address`

Comment: Thank you :) 
It showed me a way to solve the problem :) 
BTW, in my native language "Address" is written like "adres" :D 
Have a good day.

Comment: no problem! I assumed it was a different language but was just thrown off by the fact you were also using "address_line"

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can use `defaultProps` inside your component like this:

```
static defaultProps: {
  adres: {
    addresLine: null,
    selectedBranchID: null,
  }
}
```